# How can I directly supply a method reference to an optional list?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a nullable `List` of `BufferedImage`s.

```java
List<BufferedImage> list = null; // or not null.
```

I found I can flush each images in the list like this.

```java
Optional.ofNullable(list)
    .ifPresent(l -> l.forEach(i -> i.flush())); // ok
```

And I can do this.

```java
Optional.ofNullable(list)
    .ifPresent(l -> l.forEach(BufferedImage::flush)); // ok
```

Why the compiler complains when I tried to do this?

```java
Optional.ofNullable(list)
    .ifPresent(List::forEach(BufferedImage::flush)); // not ok
```

Comment: It would help things along if you'd provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, rather than just snippets.

Comment: @JonSkeet I suspect it looks like: `List<BufferedImage> list = null; Optional.ofNullable(list).ifPresent(...)`.

Comment: @assylias: Yes, it is - but it's a lot easier to get to the point of reproducing it if the OP produces a full program with all the relevant imports. It just saves a minute or two of time for *everyone* trying to help. I've got there now.

Comment: @JonSkeet Noted, and Updated.

Comment: No, that's still not a short but complete program. I can edit it to be one, if you want to see what I mean for future reference...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [method reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13) (`List::forEach`) can't take an argument so you can't compose them. On the other hand you can pass a method reference as an argument to a "normal" method call (`l.forEach(BufferedImage::flush)`).

I don't think you can do much better than your second to last option.

Answer (score 5):

It's less hassle all around to use empty lists instead of nulls.  `Optional` makes it easy:

```
Optional.ofNullable(list)
        .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)
        .forEach(BufferedImage::flush);
```